# Suggestions for E-SATA cards and/or brackets for UBUNTU 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04

I am building a JBOD rackmount backup solution using two E-SATA removable drives.

I am looking for options to reliably connect these drives to my server running Ubuntu 16.04.1.

I am looking for suggestions for a PCIe dual E-SATA card compatible with this version of Ubuntu.

In addition, I would also like to know about the reliability of using an E-SATA bracket connected to two SATA ports on my motherboard. My motherboard does support SATA drives on Ubuntu but when doing a search, I read about someone who was having problems using a bracket.

Thank you very much for any advice you can provide.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by 'E-SATA bracket'. I am using [esata to sata plates](https://www.google.se/search?q=esata%20to%20sata%20plate&client=ubuntu&hs=ebn&channel=fs&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8vNC5lojRAhWBHCwKHU2eCqUQsAQIQg&biw=1057&bih=897). They are simple and cheap and they work well. The drive is seen as a SATA drive, for example it is easy to boot Ubuntu from it.

I have not used a PCIe dual E-SATA card, so I don't know how such a card would work with Ubuntu. (I guess it would work well for data drives, but maybe it would not work for booting.)

Comment: I just want to comment that you are correct E-SATA bracket = esata to sata plate based upon the photos in the link provided. Thanks, sudodus.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck :-)